# How to update firestore cached collection on nextjs

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Lets say I have a collection of users, with the following parameters:

```
User {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    ...
    createdAt: Timestamp; // or Date
    updatedAt: Timestamp; // or Date
}
```

And in a server component on Nextjs I have a dashboard showing these users. The problem is when adding or modifying a user, the data is purged and fetched again.
How would you implement it so if the createdAt or updatedAt is newer than the last time the data was collected to add only the newer documents?

```
"use server";

export async function getUsers() {
    const firestore = getFirestore();
    const usersSnapshot = await firestore
        .collection(tables.users)
        .orderBy("updatedAt", "desc")
        .get();
    const users = <IUser[]>[];
    usersSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data();
        data.uid = doc.id;
        users.push(data as IUser);
    });
    return users;
}
```

For example:
If I have 100 users and a 101th is added. Is there a way to fetch only this last document and add it to the existing cache in NextJS?

Comment: `where("updatedAt", ">", timestampOfWhenYouLastChecked)`?